# How to suppress Underfull an Overfull warnings

Tags: warnings, overfull, underfull

How can I **suppress** Underfull an Overfull warnings?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to suppress them instead of fix them?

Comment: You surely want to figure out why the underfull (badness 10000) warnings are happening.  My guess is that you are ending lines inappropriately with `\\ `.  That's not the way to end a paragraph.  And the fact that so many paragraphs have multiple underfull lines makes me think you are using something like `\sloppy`; that should be a last resort.  We could make better guesses if we could see some of the affected material, and even better, a small compilable example showing the input for some of these problem areas.

Comment: Yes. At first, I would like to suppress them all. Is it possible? My example is too big to present . I looked for something like  **\ WarningFilter {latex} {Underfull \ hbox}**  but it doesn't work. Then if it works, I can cut my example out and show it. But I'm afraid I did it on purpose and they should stay, and that's not the end of the paragraph but equations which I have to correct but on this moment I need to suppres warnings because they disrtact me.

Comment: you can (but should not) set \hbadness=10000 and \hfuzz=\maxdimen but this is a duplicate, I'll find an answer